# Retrieve var value from another class

Tags: ios, class, swift, xcode6

i have those two classes and i want to retrieve a value from one to another:

```
    class SearchUserViewController:UIViewController{

        var selectedUser: String!

    @IBAction func btn_accept(sender: AnyObject) {
            selectedUser = "Norolimba"
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I'm saving the value to "selectedUser" var, then i want to check the value from this class:

```
class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let vc : SearchUserViewController! = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchView") as SearchUserViewController
        println("\(vc.selectedUser)")
        if vc.selectedUser == nil {
            self.requestData("team")
        }else{
            self.requestData("user")
        }
    }
}
```

But when i println the value "vc.selectedUser" the value is nil. So what can i do here to catch it from the other class and don't get a nil value?

searchView is here:
[image]

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()`, you're *not* accessing the view controller that was being displayed on the screen, nor are you accessing the controller that has potentially been automatically instantiated by Interface Builder.

What you're doing is *instantiating* (hence the name) a *new instance* of that controller. So the instance variable `selectedUser` of that new instance is going to be `nil`.

What you should do is probably provide a callback to your `SearchUserViewController` when you display it, so that it can notify the view that presented it when a user is picked.

Alternatively, you can use the `parentViewController` property of `UIViewController` in cases where you (the view controller) are being presented modally to access the view controller that presented you. So in your `SearchUserViewController`, when it's being dismissed, it can access `self.parentViewController`, which should be a `CalendarViewController`, and call a method or set a property.

*(But for the modal controller to assume who its parent is, is a bit of a code smell. I recommend using a callback or delegate of some sort.)*

**Edit:** An example of using the completion callback:

```
class CalendarViewController : UIViewController {

    public func displayUserSelectionController() {
        let suvc : SearchUserViewController = ... (how are you displaying it?) ...
        self.presentViewController(suvc, animated:true, completion: {
            // The SUVC is hiding
            if let user = suvc.selectedUser {
                self.requestData("team")
            } else {
                self.requestData("user")
            }
        })
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: then what would be the result? I don't understand exactly what i have to do. Use `parentViewController`, but how? Thanks @Craig Otis

Comment: I've used NSUserDefaults instead. It does the job, but i don't want to do this cause i'm sure its not necessary

Comment: Yea, `NSUserDefaults` is definitely not the solution here. I've added a quick solution using the `completion` argument of the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method. I typed it from memory, so you may need to fiddle with the syntax.

Comment: i was not intending do display the view, just to put it in a var and then check for the var value, so i don't need to use `self.presentViewController`, i mean, its just to see the value of `selectedUser` in the other viewController. Dunno if you know what i mean. But i appreciate your comments. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you've already displayed the view, then you need to maintain a reference to it so that you can query it for a property. Without knowing your application/view controller structure, it's hard to be more specific.